# I have created a script that I want to run when my computer starts up, but it only opens the file

Tags: windows, startup, startupscript

The script file I have created only opens the file itself when the computer starts up. It will not simply run. What can i do to get it to run rather than just open the file?

Comment: is it on Windows or Linux?

Comment: I am using windows